# Second network interface fails to start: pre-start killed by TERM

Tags: networking, server, vmware

Running Ubuntu Server 12.04.3 LTS on our VMWare cluster.
After adding a second nic I face the following problems.

When booting not both interfaces are coming up only one of them and the weird thing is it is random which interface.

I than have to manually `ifup` the corresponding interface.

The `/etc/network/interfaces` is correctly setup.

Allready looked at `dmesg`, `kern.log` and `boot.log`

Only error I can find is:

```
[5.952693] init: network-interface (eth0) pre-start process (679) killed by TERM signal
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem and the issue seemed to be related to having open-iscsi tools installed.  I looked in `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-up.d`, and eyeballed the files that were there to see what was running as part of the `ifup` command.

In my case, I had installed the iscsi tools for some testing and no longer needed it, so it was easy to remove and re-test to see if the interface came up.  It did.

In the end I had these files in `if-up.d`: bind9, ntpdate, openntpd, openssh-server, postfix, and upstart.

Note: I did not have any "up" scripts in my `/etc/network/interfaces` file, so that's why I started looking at these directories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem on Ubuntu 12.04 after "open-iscsi" package installation.
   That package was needed and i couldn't just delete it )).

Problem was in scripts

```
/etc/network/if-up.d/open-iscsi
/etc/network/if-down.d/open-iscsi
```

If VM has several network interfaces, then several instances of open-iscsi init script executed on system boot. Several of them try to load iscsi kernel modules and start iscsi daemon simultaneously. So one finished successfully, others - failed and stop process of setting IP on their network interfaces.

Solution:

```
rm /etc/network/if-up.d/open-iscsi
rm /etc/network/if-down.d/open-iscsi
update-rc.d open-iscsi defaults
```